# Regular expression to find ellipses using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

How do I write a regular expression to find ellipses in a text file using VBScript? the text will be look something like this

```
 >…………………………………………………………………………………………………………………<
```

that I want to find, and replace with something else.

I've tried the following as the search pattern to no avail:

```
">[\133]*<"
">[…]*<"
">[\133]+<"
">[…]+<"
">[\133]{1,}<"
">[…]{1,}<"
">[\x85]+<"
```

The first one finds the zero case, but not if an ellipse occurs between the >< characters. Several work when using Notepad++ regular expressions. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found how to do it.

```
">[\W]{2,}<"
```

does it in my file, since the ellipses aren't characters.

Answer (score 0):

In the above context, I can't help but think that a regular expression is a bit overkill, but I had a quick look: `\>…+\<` will work - it won't capture anything, though, but you could put some parentheses around it if you wanted...

The ellipses ***is*** a character. From what I can see, ellipsis is ASCII #133. The character used in **your** question, however, is something else entirely. They register as ASCII #226 for reasons I can't quite work out. Hopefully someone smarter than me might know the answer. In any event, assuming it is `CHR(133)`, it should be easy enough to construct a string pattern in VBScript to accomplish the above.